# system of 1st order ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given is the system of first order ODEs with initial value:
>
> $x'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & \alpha & \beta\\ 3 & \gamma
> > &
> > \alpha\end{matrix}\right)x(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}e^{3t}\\e^{3t}\\-e^{3t}\end{matrix}\right),x(0)=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\\-2\end{matrix}\right)$
>
> 1. Determine $\alpha,\beta, \gamma\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $\left(\begin{matrix}0\\e^{3t}cos(t)\\-e^{3t}sin(t)\end{matrix}\right)$
>      is a solution of the homogeneus system.
> 2. Determine the solution of the initial value problem, with the $\alpha,\beta, \gamma\in\mathbb{Z}$ from question 1.
> 3. Find a solution to the initial value problem using the solution in question 2.
>
> $x'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & \alpha & 0 &\beta\\
> > \frac{9}{(t+1)^{2}} & 0 & -\frac{3}{(t+1)} & 0\\ 3 & \gamma & 0 &
> > \alpha\end{matrix}\right)x(t)+\left(\begin{matrix}e^{3t}\\e^{3t}\\0\\-e^{3t}\end{matrix}\right),x(0)=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\2\\3\\-2\end{matrix}\right)$
>
> Notice that the matrix has non-constant coëfficiënts on the 3th row,
>   and column 3 of the matrix contains zeros except on the 3th place in
>   this row.

My solution:

**question 1:**

$x'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & \alpha & \beta\\ 3 & \gamma & \alpha\end{matrix}\right)x(t)$

$x(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\e^{3t}cos(t)\\-e^{3t}sin(t)\end{matrix}\right)\longrightarrow x'(t)=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\3e^{3t}cos(t)-e^{3t}sin(t)\\-3e^{3t}sin(t)-e^{3t}cos(t)\end{matrix}\right)$

so

$x'(t)=A\cdot x(t)$

and

$0=2\cdot 0$

$3e^{3t}cos(t)-e^{3t}sin(t)=1\cdot 0+\alpha\cdot e^{3t}cos(t) -\beta\cdot e^{3t}sin(t)$

$-3e^{3t}sin(t)-e^{3t}cos(t)=3\cdot 0 + \gamma\cdot e^{3t}cos(t) - \alpha\cdot e^{3t}sin(t)$

That gives us:
$\gamma =-1$, $\alpha=3$ and $\beta=1$

and

$A=\left(\begin{matrix}2 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 3 & 1\\ 3 & -1 & 3\end{matrix}\right)$

**Question 2:**

First i find the solution to the homogeneous problem:

the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the matrix A are:

$r_{1}=2$, $\varepsilon_{1} =\left(\begin{matrix}2\\ 2\\-1\end{matrix}\right)$, 
$r_{2}=3-i$, $\varepsilon_{2}=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 1\\i\end{matrix}\right)$,
$r_{3}=3+i$, $\varepsilon_{3}=\left(\begin{matrix}0\\ 1\\-i\end{matrix}\right)$

Then i transform $\varepsilon_{2}e^{r_{2}t}$ and $\varepsilon_{3}e^{r_{3}t}$ to real functions. The solution of the homogeneous problem is:

$\left(\begin{matrix}x_{1}(t)\\x_{2}(t)\\x_{3}(t)\end{matrix}\right)=C1\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}2\\2\\-1\end{matrix}\right)\cdot e^{2t}+C2\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}0\\cos(t)\\-sin(t)\end{matrix}\right)\cdot e^{3t}+C3\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}0\\sin(t)\\cos(t)\end{matrix}\right)\cdot e^{3t}$

How do i find the particular solution to this problem??

**question 3:**

How do i solve this problem?? It is obvious that i have to do something with that 3th row, but still i do not have a clue...

Answer (score 0):

Ok via variation of the parameters i was able to find a solution of the particular problem. The particular solution is:

$\left(\begin{matrix}e^{3t}\\ 2e^{3t}\\-2e^{3t}\end{matrix}\right)$

However i still have no clue how to solve question 3?